# Json.Net custom serialization

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json.net

```
[
 {
"articles": [
  [
    "2016-03-04",
    6
  ],
  [
    "2016-03-05",
    10
  ],
  [
    "2016-03-06",
    11
  ]      
],    
"accession": "00000446-201301000-00018"
 },  
{
"articles": [
  [
    "2016-03-04",
    1
  ],     
  [
    "2016-03-08",
    17
  ],
  [
    "2016-03-09",
    10
  ]
],   
"accession": "00000446-201301000-00019"
}]
```

List is input `{ "Accession"= "00000446-201301000-00018", "Date"= "635926464000000000","Rank" =2},{ "Accession" = "00000446-201301000-00019", "Date" = "635931648000000000","Rank" = 2}`

I want json data exactly like this,data is coming from list and list is dynamically growing.Form list, I want all dates and rank club to gether for the same accession number.
I want to use newtonsoft json custom serlization to convert my list to json.

Comment: Can you try to edit your question to improve the language?  I cannot understand what you are trying to do.  I see two JSON samples but I cannot tell which is input and which is output -- if either.  What have you tried so far?  What language are you using -- [tag:c#] or something else?  What do your classes (if any) look like?  See [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then try to create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Model

```
  public  class FinalList
  {
    public string accession {get;set;}
    public List<ArticlesDetails>   Articles{get;set;}
  }

  public  class ArticlesDetails
  {
    public DateTime Date{get;set;}
    public int number{get;set;}
  }
```

> Use ObjectContent instead of StringContent so we let the formatter (i.e. JsonMediaTypeFormatter) to deal with the serialization and deserialization

In config

```
       config.Formatters.Insert(0, new YourCustomFormatter());
       config.Formatters.Insert(1, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

> and disable post in your custom formatter so that JsonMediaTypeFormatter desrializes  the complex data

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do does not need any Custom Formatter, you just have to re-structure your data, Here is an example for restructuring a list based on `Entity` class to the new required one.

```
class Entity
{
    public string Accession { get; set; }
    public string Date { get; set; }
    public int Rank { get; set; }
}
```

Add this line if you need to read the list from Json

```
        var list = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Entity>>(input);
```

Here is the code for changing the structure of data to array based articles.

```
        var translatedAsArray = list.GroupBy(e => e.Accession)
             .Select(g =>
        new {
            //change new 'object[]' to 'new' to make the article an object
            //you can convert i.Date, i.Rank and g.Key to anything you want here
            Articles = g.Select(i => new object[] { i.Date , i.Rank }),  
            Accessing = g.Key
           }
        );

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(translatedAsArray, Formatting.Indented);
```